Apache alias throws You don't have permission to access error
I want setting alias
Problem : DocumentRoot is C:/xampp/htdocs  else  set
Alias /images/ "D:/images"
<Directory "D:/images">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Call path 'http://localhost/images/'
Message is "You don't have permission to access this resource. "
Do I need to install anything additional?

Have a try using "Options +Indexes" if you want to access the index of that folder. And make sure that the http server process actually does have access to that folder in the file system.

Thank you for the answer. But still no results

And you are sure that "D:/images" is a valid path on your system? I ask because I have very little experience on MS Windows systems and I am not familiar with that strange notation. I would expect "D:\images" or "/D/images". but maybe the http server maps that correctly. Just asking.

Thank you very much for helping me. I can solve this problem. I just add    "/"  example  Alias /images/ "D:/images/"
<Directory "D:/images/">
AllowOverride all
Require all granted


I just add /:
Alias /images/ "D:/images/"
<Directory "D:/images/">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

